# Is it possible to simulate the Physical Server IPMI in any platform such as VMWare workstation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, ipmi

Is it possible to simulate the Physical Server IPMI in any platform such as VMWare workstation?

You know the Physical Server have BMC board with IPMI in it.

so we can use a controller server to communicative to each Physical Server via IPMI.

but in VMWare I do not found the VM have this function, so how can I simulate this function? and is there any platform have this function?